# How to get the exact week number if the week is starting with specified weekday on moment js?

Tags: momentjs

Example:

Week day is starting from

`moment().weekYear(yearValue).week(weekNumber).startOf('week').weekday(2)`

which is Tuesday.

First week on 2017 the days are,

```
[3-Jan-2017, 4-Jan-2017, 5-Jan-2017, 6-Jan-2017, 7-Jan-2017, 8-Jan-2017, 9-Jan-2017]
```

How to get the exact week number for `1-Jan-2017`?

Answer (score 0):

Week numbers can be retrieved by:

```
var weeknumber = moment("1-Jan-2017", "d-MMM-YYYY", "en").week();
```

And be careful, passing the locale might change the week number because of starting on Monday or Dunday.

Answer (score 0):

```
var weeknumber = moment("1-Jan-2017").week();
```

In my application I've served the locale globally depending on what language the user has logged in with, so I wouldn't worry about that.